# Import data from Snowflake with single sign on into R

Tags: r, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I import data directly from a Snowflake database into an R?  I was able to do this by creating an ODBC connection with my Snowflake credentials; however, my company switched Snowflake to single sign on and I'm unable to get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly connect to Snowflake using R and I would highly recommend that you use [RJDBC](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html) library. Two requirements are to install the RJDBC library and download [snowflake’s jar file](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/). *(needless to say, make sure jar file is safe somewhere on your drive that it can not be deleted or moved accidentally)*. You may pick a version of jar files, say, [3.6.6](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.6.6/snowflake-jdbc-3.6.6.jar).

```
# load library
library(RJDBC)

# specify driver
jdbcDriver <- JDBC(driverClass="net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver", 
                classPath="/home/username/R/snowflake-jdbc-3.6.6.jar") # <-- this is where I saved the jar file

# create a connection
# this is the most critical part.
# you have to make sure you enter your SSO path as well as corp username with domain
con <- dbConnect(jdbcDriver, "jdbc:snowflake://company.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com/?authenticator=https://your_domain_name.okta.com/", 
                        'username@domain.com', 'password')

# to query data
# at this point, you are good to go. start querying data.
dbGetQuery(con, "select current_timestamp() as now")
```

Answer (score 3):

We support OKTA single sign on from ODBC. Please follow https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html for steps to configure your ODBC DSN.